# Notepad++ v4.2.2. regular expressions to match and replace all text between two tags

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a large file with a lot of `<h1></h1>` tags with various text between it. I'm searching for a way to remove all text between those tags, which might also include newline chars.

Any help would be appreciated.

Update: Tried this, but doesn't work... (ofcourse cursor was at begin of file)

[image]

Comment: Do you also want to remove the tag along with the text inside? If the `<h1>` tag can be nested inside `<h1>` tag, you may need to do it manually.

Comment: Note that all the solutions below would fail if the `<h1>` tags for some reason is nested inside another `<h1>` tag.

Comment: if "for some reason" there is a h1 inside another h1 the html is messed up

Comment: Yes I want to remove it later. But I wanted the question to be as clear as possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Select `. matches new line` and `regular expression` option

Find what:`<h1>.*?</h1>`

Replace with:`<h1></h1>`

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. I have v4.2.2. and don't have those options you mentioned. Also the regex doesn't work...

Comment: @keun: Then update your Notepad++! I'm running v6.2.2. I wouldn't be surprised if it's simply impossible with such an old version.

Comment: You are so right. Didn't realize it might not have worked due to older version... Installed 6.3 and it works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

find:

```
<h1>.*?</h1>
```

replace with:

```
<h1></h1>
```